# Writing file with <fstream>/FILE in C/C++

Tags: c, file, memory, stream, fstream

I am a bit perplexed by the way FILE/fstream systems described in C/C++. For instance, I want to write a file which I know the size of beforehand, just like any image (for instance tga with 18 bytes header and let's say `3 * (10 ^ 6)` bytes for pixels).

First question, when I create a stream and write data to it, does it get written directly to the chunk of memory in the hard drive? And how much memory it reserves initially in the case if it's consistent value.

Then, in the case when there is not enough contiguous memory at the place the stream is being written to I guess it gets reallocated at another bigger chunk. Can I specify the size of the stream while creating it? To let's say being able to write first header and then bitmap not being afraid that there would be reallocation if bitmap is too big for the current sequence of memory.

Or should I just write to the stream with one array or struct that way avoiding possible reallocations?

Comment: It depends on the filesystem, but most handle files that are not contiguous just fine. You just open the file and write whatever you like to it and the operating system will handle it in an appropriate way.

Comment: Most file systems will not "reallocate" the file, but just write as much as fits in one place, and then continue somewhere else on the disk. The filesystem keeps track of any segments used, and still treat it as a contiguous stream of data.